# Burninate meta tag [non-technical]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

The [non-technical](/questions/tagged/non-technical) tag is a terrible meta tag and any questions that could be tagged [non-technical](/questions/tagged/non-technical) would be very off topic on StackOverflow.

Most of the questions on this tag are already closed. I suggest we close or re-tag the remaining [open questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnon-technical%5D+closed%3Ano) then burninate the tag.